# using mongoDB collection in one page twice

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

Hi2all!
I have:
1) mongo collection:

```
[{_id:ObjectId("5b0d5fb624d22e1b4843c06b")
collectionName:"collection0"
collectionCaption:"caption1"}

{_id:ObjectId("5b0d5fb824d22e1b4843d4c1")
collectionName:"collection1"
collectionCaption:"caption1"}

{_id:ObjectId("5b0d5fb924d22e1b4843d74a")
collectionName:"collection2"
collectionCaption:"caption1"}

{_id:ObjectId("5b0d5fb924d22e1b4843d7b0")
collectionName:"collection3"
collectionCaption:"caption1"}]
```

2) flask app with the view:

```
def index():
    a = mongo.db.collectionsNames.find()
    return render_template('index.html', collectionsNames=a)
```

3) templates: index.html witch extend base.html.
base.html:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %} 
{% block content %}
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        {% for asd in collectionsNames %}
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/{{ asd["collectionName"] }}">{{ asd["collectionCaption"] }}</a>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
    {% block contentBase %} {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block contentBase %}
    {% for zxc in collectionsNames %}
        {{ zxc["collectionName"] }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The question is: why if base and index using the same variable of collection, index template show nothing?

But if in view code is:

```
def index():
        a = mongo.db.collectionsNames.find()
        b = mongo.db.collectionsNames.find()
        return render_template('index.html', collectionsNames1=a, collectionsNames2=b)
```

and in templates i am using the different variables, the index template show me the data.

Comment: and if in view function code is: 

a = [{"collectionName":"collection0", "collectionCaption":"col1"},
         {"collectionName": "collection1", "collectionCaption": "col2"},
         {"collectionName": "collection2", "collectionCaption": "col3"},
         ]
return render_template('index.html', collectionsNames=a)

then index template show me the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mongo.db.collectionsNames.find()` returns a cursor: `print(mongo.db.collectionsNames.find())` gives `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7fd3854d5710>`.

To make it easy (but kind of wrong) a cursor is a specific kind of instance that fetch data from the database chunk by chunk so if you want the 1 000 000 first items in db you don't actually store 1M items in RAM, you iterate 100 by 100 items (for example). Cursor handle that in a magic way.

Whatever, you cannot loop several time on the same cursor and you should never caste a cursor to list like `list(cursor_instance)` (because if your query ask for 1M product, doing this add all these products in RAM).

---

So, now, how can you handle this. Most of time I would say it's better to call the method when you need it, twice if needed.

But here you are in a Jinja environment and if I'm right calling methods within a Jinja template is impossible.

A way to do that is to use properties.

```
class LazyCollection(object):

    @property
    def collections_names(self):
         return mongo.db.collectionsNames.find()


lazycoll = LazyCollection()
return render_template('index.html', collectionsNames=lazycoll)
```

Then, in your template:

```
{% for asd in collectionsNames.collections_names %}
    <p>{{ asd.foo }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for such wide answer.
But, your method with property is dont work, the index template still show nothing.
As i understand, the only way is to use different variables for each for loops. As for me it is bad and not so "flexibly"...

Comment: As i understant this is feature of pymongo library (of the cursor...)  not of python at all.